# Python script for postgres table partitioning

Tags: python, postgresql, pyspark

I want to write python script to partition postgres table based on months for the given year, if that month already exists in database pass else create partition for that month. Kindly suggest

pyspark , using for loop to iterate over

Answer (score 0):

I once did something like this. It may need adaptation for the specific situation. It also needs to be executed on the database.

```py
"""
Generate SQL for adding partitions 
"""
SCHEMA_NAME = 'something'
TABLE_NAME = 'other'
YEAR_START = 2023
YEAR_END = 2024

for y in range(YEAR_START, YEAR_END + 1):
    for m in range(1, 13):
        if m == 12:
            print(f'create table if not exists {SCHEMA_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}_{y:04d}_{m:02d} partition of ' +
                  f'{SCHEMA_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} for values from ' +
                  f'(\'{y:04d}-{m:02d}-01 00:00:00\') to ' + f'(\'{y+1:04d}-01-01 00:00:00\');')
        else:
            print(f'create table if not exists {SCHEMA_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}_{y:04d}_{m:02d} partition of ' +
                  f'{SCHEMA_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} for values from ' +
                  f'(\'{y:04d}-{m:02d}-01 00:00:00\') to ' + f'(\'{y:04d}-{m+1:02d}-01 00:00:00\');')
```